# MongoDB: Lost dry run election due to internal error

Tags: replication, mongodb

I am trying to solve a Replication issue here in MongoDB 4.2, but I can no longer get my Primary server back to primary, it always stays in SECONDARY mode. I've tried several types of solutions, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914281/how-to-convert-a-mongodb-replica-set-to-a-stand-alone-server/31745150#31745150) Or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22917523/mongodb-replica-set-no-primary-need-to-force-new-primary)

But without success.

In the logs, I came across these messages:

```
 Scheduling remote command request for vote request: RemoteCommand 729 -- target:mongo2:27021 db:admin cmd:{ replSetRequestVotes: 1, setName: "MyReplicaSet", dryRun: true, term: 2, candidateIndex: 0, configVersion: 125668, lastCommittedOp: { ts: Timestamp(1570799675, 1), t: 2 } }
 2019-10-11T11:17:25.041-0300 I  ELECTION [replexec-2] VoteRequester(term 2 dry run) received an invalid response from mongo2:27021: NotYetInitialized: no replset config has been received; response message: { operationTime: Timestamp(0, 0), ok: 0.0, errmsg: "no replset config has been received", code: 94, codeName: "NotYetInitialized", $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1570799675, 1), signature: { hash: BinData(0, 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000), keyId: 0 } } }
 2019-10-11T11:17:25.041-0300 I  ELECTION [replexec-2] not running for primary, we received insufficient votes
 2019-10-11T11:17:25.041-0300 I  ELECTION [replexec-2] Lost dry run election due to internal error
```

How to fix this? Possible a bug? I have tried 4.0.12 and It is work fine

Comment: How many members do you have in your replica set?

Comment: just one, I belive it is a bug. I make a downgrade for 4.0.12 and it is run fine!